# HTML5 Local Storage for Notification Bar

Tags: local-storage

I have a message bar that I made, but am not the best with scripting, so not sure how to handle the local storage

Here is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/nDtWM/11/

```
// It should be persistent until the user clears the cache
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Checks to see if it is the first visit on browser open
if(sessionStorage.firstVisit != true) {
    // Stores visit
    sessionStorage.firstVisit = true;
    $('#how-to').show();
} else {
    $('#how-to').hide();
}
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#how-to").hide();
});  
});
```

I believe I have it rigged so it is persistent until the user clears the cache, but am not sure. Also, it does not work so I cannot know :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

sessonStorage only lasts until the user closes their browser. You probably want to use localStorage instead.

Also the storage values are always stored as strings so you need to use them as strings or convert them into whatever you want.

Comment: You changed it to use localStorage which was good but you're still comparing a string (localStorage.firstVisit) to a boolean (!= true). For what you're trying to do you, you probably only need to make sure localStorage.firstVisit exists.